# What should be the namespace used in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

In my ASP.NET Core Web API project, I want to use methods like `HttpPost`, `HttpGet`, `HttpDelete`. When I've added that onto the action, IntelliSense suggests these three namespaces:

```
System.Web.Mvc 
System.Web.Http
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
```

Which one should be used and why?

Comment: does [the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.httpgetattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0) help?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann , I think not, because my question is, which namespace should I use when implementing the Http Methods on WEB API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc** is the default namespace when you create an Asp.NET Core Web API in VisualStudio. There is no need to depend on your project on other namespaces.

You can also read this document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc?view=aspnetcore-5.0

for example :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CoreWebApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: should I use this? But I don't have any View Support like the answer of @fatameh. I am just going to call this API on my 3rd Party Application.

Comment: @LevesqueXylia yes, if you only want a web API feature this is enough Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.

Comment: @LevesqueXylia I Also recommend these tutorials: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_core/index.htm,  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` and `System.Web.Mvc` are exactly the same
if you have View support, then use Mvc, This will support Mvc Design pattern

if not (you are simply calling third party apps) then use `System.Web.Http`

Take a look at this => [What is the different between System.Web.Http.HttpPut Vs System.Web.Mvc.HttpPut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178056/what-is-the-different-between-system-web-http-httpput-vs-system-web-mvc-httpput)

and this => [For MVC 4, what's the difference between Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc and System.Web.Mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101831/for-mvc-4-whats-the-difference-between-microsoft-aspnet-mvc-and-system-web-mvc)

Comment: So, should I use `System.Web.Http`? Because I am just going to call this API on my 3rd party application?

Comment: if you are building a web api (which I think you are) use Mvc

Comment: Thank you for this Sir. If only I could accept more than 1 answer. I will accept this too. You both help me undestand this namespaces. Thank you!!!